# How to show autofill suggestion without managed shared credentials? React native IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, keychain, autofill, associated-domains

I have this task that need to show the suggested username & password on my app.

something like this that I found [credits to this site]

https://brainsandbeards.com/blog/quick-change-that-helps-ios-users-sign-in-quicker

[image]

or something like this

[Other way to autofill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjK1V.jpg)

But every time I press the 'password' on the top of the keyboard it always goes directly to the list of keychains and not giving the option like the above image showing a suggested account or choose other passwords.

I even followed this documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_associated-domains

even use an 'alternate-mode' on the associated domain.

I suspect that the webserver we're using is not managed shared credentials enabled server?
Is there a possibility to do this without associated-domain capability?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear, add some code related to this part or explain a little bit more, or even prepare your re-produced issue and publish it on [snack.expo.dev](https://snack.expo.dev) and it would be very easy for us to help you.

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? Then you could answer your own question. 